# Did the Raphael.js animation method change for the 2.0 release?

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

This often-referenced Raphael.js [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-introduction-to-the-raphael-js-library/) from 2009 (see "example 6") animates in jsfiddle with Raphael version 1.5.2 but not with version 2.0. It *renders*, it just doesn't *animate*.

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);

var tetronimo = paper.path("M 250 250 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 50 l -50 0 l 0 50 z");

tetronimo.attr(
   {
       gradient: '90-#526c7a-#64a0c1',
       stroke: '#3b4449',
       'stroke-width': 10,
       'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
       rotation: -90
   }
);

tetronimo.animate({rotation: 360}, 2000, 'bounce');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdW3u/

Why? There doesn't appear to be a different "animate" syntax, (although there's no changelog, so that isn't perfectly clear.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation attribute has been replaced with the transform attribute, try this:

```
tetronimo.animate({'transform':"r360"}, 2000, 'bounce');
```

Comment: Thanks Imran. Yeah, I finally figured that out just by trial and error. Can you recommend a source explaining the current version in more detail? Seems like a lot of the Raphael tutorials are outdated...

Comment: Hi Ben, my pleasure. Here is a link to the official API reference http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element although I was unable to find anything that explains the change that was made.